# Advanced filter : Error 1004 when I replace plain text with a date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that works fine when the headers are text (like 'date 1', 'date 2', ...), but date 1, 2 .... should be actual dates, that can be found in another sheet (and initially come from a pivot table).

So as soon as I replace 'date 1' with either a date like 01/08/2023 or a formule to get the date from another sheet, it goes wrong, I get a runtime error 1004 on this line :

```
ShtSource.Range("A13").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange, CopyToRange
```

This is the complete code :

---

```
Sub Proposal()
    
    ' voorstel om door te sturen naar de klant
    
    Dim c As Range
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ShtSource As Worksheet: Set ShtSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Voorstel")
    Dim CopyToRange As Range: Set CopyToRange = Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(2, 6)
    Dim CriteriaRange As Range: Set CriteriaRange = CopyToRange.Offset(, 8).Resize(2, 1)
    
    CopyToRange.Resize(1) = Array(ShtSource.[a13], ShtSource.[b13], ShtSource.[d13], ShtSource.[f13], ShtSource.[h13], ShtSource.[j13])
    CriteriaRange.Value = Application.Transpose(Array("# Pal", "<>0"))
    ShtSource.Range("A13").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange, CopyToRange
    
    CriteriaRange.ClearContents
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Range("A1").Select
    Range("A1").Activate
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 15773696
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B1:F1").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Columns("A:G").Select
    Range("A1").Activate
    Columns("A:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
    
End Sub
```

---

I have no idea why this code won't work anymore as soon as I replace a cell with text with a date in that same cell, I tried different formats, but that doesn't work either.

Anyone has a clue what could be the issue?

This is what my file looks like :

[image]

this is what I need as result :

[image]

Comment: What is the intended result of this code? What formats have you tried, storing the dates as text (not general but forced texted, even a ' if needed)? I think the best thing to do is get some Debug.Print(TypeName())'s in there to check the types of the dates you are filtering: excel sometimes doesn't change the format when it should

Comment: The intended result of the code is a  creating a new list with only those lines where there is a quantity filled in.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `CopyToRange` parameter of the `Range.AdvancedFilter` method.

First, I reduced your code to a much shorter test case:

```
Sub CopyErrorTest()
    
    Dim ShtSource As Worksheet: Set ShtSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim CopyToRange As Range: Set CopyToRange = Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(2, 6)
    Dim CriteriaRange As Range: Set CriteriaRange = CopyToRange.Offset(, 8).Resize(2, 1)
    
    CopyToRange.Resize(1) = Array(ShtSource.[a13], ShtSource.[b13], ShtSource.[d13], ShtSource.[f13], ShtSource.[h13], ShtSource.[j13])
    CriteriaRange.Value = Application.Transpose(Array("# Pal", "<>0"))
    
    ShtSource.Range("A13").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange, CopyToRange
    
    CriteriaRange.ClearContents
    
End Sub
```

In my test case, I entered the date 1/8/2023 instead of datum 1 in B13.  Then, I got the error you were getting.  Try this for yourself.  You'll see that the workbook it creates has copied the headers over, but the format for the date isn't there, it's converted to a general format.  This changes the test in the cell on the new workbook.  Since the range's contents aren't the same on the new sheet, it throws an error.  So, you need to change the formatting of the cells with dates in the new sheet.  You can do that with the `Range.NumberFormat` method.

In my test example, adding this line:

```
CopyToRange.Cells(1, 2).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
```

just before the `AdvanceFilter` line fixes the issue, because I am changing the date format (and therefore text in the cell) to match the range that we're copying from.  (Keep in mind that you're probably not using this date format, as this is the American format.)

As a general note, when your code isn't working as expected, try to create a very simple test case to replicate the problem.  This is much easier to follow and debug, and then you can take the results back to your "real" code.

Comment: I have added the numberformat line, and that helps to get the dates in the correct format, however this code still doesn't work, it only works when there is a text in the header, but as soon as I replace it with dates, it goes wrong. I have spend several hours on figuring out why this doesn't work, and it's a code that I also use in a similar file, and I don't see any reasons why it doesn't work in my current file. I have added a screenshot of what I want as result in my original post.

Comment: Any help in finding a solution is much appreciated, perhaps the the code itself could be done a totally different way ?